# Error - Attribute 'android:testOnly' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, runtime, dropbox

I'm trying to run the example "DBRoulette" in the DropBox Android SDK:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/android

When I build the project in the Android Studio (Build --> Rebuild Project) I get no errors, but when I'm trying to run the code on my device (from the Android Studio) I get the error:

> "attribute 'android:testOnly' not found"

I can see the line:

```
android:testOnly="true"
```

in the "AndroidManifest.xml" file but as I understand I cannot edit this file and change it to `testOnly=false`.

What is the problem? Why am I getting this error?

(If it's important I'm using Gradle-4.5.1)

---

Here is the full build message that I'm getting:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
D:\AndroidProjects\DropboxSDK-1.6.3\DBRouletteTest\app\build\intermediates\manifests\instant-run\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(12) error: attribute 'android:testOnly' not found.
Error:(12) attribute 'android:testOnly' not found.
Error:failed processing manifest.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED in 0s
Information:6 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

---

And here is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dropbox.android.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:testOnly="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.android.sample.DBRoulette"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
                <data android:scheme="db-CHANGE_ME" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.dropbox.android.sample.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:multiprocess="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: By the way, unrelated to the issue itself, per the warning at the top of [the page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/android), that example app is for Dropbox API v1, which is now retired. You should instead use [the Dropbox API v2 Java SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java). There's [an example Android for that](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Changing compileSdkVersion to more higher in the `build.gradle`. I changed my compileSdkVersion to 28, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it, perhaps. In the end I managed to launch the app by doing the following:

Copy my `AndroidManifest.xml` and enter your Key.
Add your Key and Secret in the DBRoulette.class.
In the `build.gradle(Module:app)` file, change the minimum sdk from 3 to 4.

This has worked for me, since the android:testOnly feature isn't availeable in the API 3 (according to Android Studio's Warnings)
If what I told you works it was a problem generated by the API 3, and close the question by marking this as correct, otherwise explain further issues.

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dropbox.android.sample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".DBRoulette"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
            <data android:scheme="db-YOUR_TOKEN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: OK I added the "AndroidManifest.xml" file as you asked, does it helps?

Comment: I have tried your "AndroidManifest.xml" file (I changed to my APP_KEY) but still the same error.

Comment: I tried to re-adding it in manually, I tried to delete this line, I also tried to change the value to "false". In all cases the Rebuid Project is OK without any errors, but when I try to run it I get the error and the testOnly=true is there again with some more modifications.

Comment: Are you using the Api v1 or the latest?